# wincache session file size limit

Tags: php, session, wincache

I have implemented wincache with IIS in windows and enabled scache with maximum size of 85MB. But the problem now is after it hit 85MB, my PHP application has problem logging in. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a different session provider that is not constrained by the same size limitations as WinCache?  Have you considered session.save_handler = files ?